# Uncaught (in promise) Error: already ended using pdf-merger-js module

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdfmerger

**Context**

I'm developping a vueJS component dedicated to pdf manipulation. The goal is to allow the user to upload multiple pdf files, delete some pages and reorganize all the pages in a specific order.

**Code**

I have an array of file nammed `pdfFiles`. Every time the user drop a new pdf file i store the blob in this array.

There is an array nammed `pages`. This array store every pages of every imported pdf files. The objects strored in this array have the following structure :

```js
pageObject: {
    pdfFileIndex: Integer,
    index: Integer,
    id: Integer,
    page: PDFPageProxy
}
```

`page` which is an autogenerated object from PDF.js lib and `id` are not important for the exemple.

`pdfFileIndex` is an Interger corresponding to the index of the file in the `pdfFiles` array the page is associated to.

`index` simply is the index of the page in his pdf file.

When the user ended the manipulation of the files i use the following code to generate a pdf containing only the pages keept by the user :

```
exportPdf() {
    (async () => {
        this.pages.forEach(page => {
            console.log(this.pdfFiles[page.pdfFileIndex]);
            console.log([page.index]);
            this.merger.add(this.pdfFiles[page.pdfFileIndex], [page.index]);
        });

        return await this.merger.saveAsBlob();
    })();
}
```

`this.merger` have been initialized as : `merger: new PDFMerger()` in the data scope.

So `this.pdfFiles[page.pdfFileIndex]` contains the blob of the file and `[page.index]` contains the index of the page i want to add to the merger object.

I used some console.log to check if both of these values were corresponding to what the user did in the editor and it is.

**Issue**

I have an issue on the `this.merger.saveAsBlob()` step which is :

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: already ended
at eval (fragment.js?2c29:10)
at Object../node_modules/pdfjs/lib/fragment.js (chunk-vendors.js:3656)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
at fn (app.js:151)
at Object.eval (document.js?07b2:4)
at eval (document.js:813)
at Object../node_modules/pdfjs/lib/document.js (chunk-vendors.js:3572)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
at fn (app.js:151)
at eval (index.js?4e59:3)
```

There is only one post that relate this issue on the github of the module which is this one : https://github.com/nbesli/pdf-merger-js/issues/29.

The fact is that my problem isn't the same because i only call the "exportPdf" function once in the application.

**If more code or explanations are needed just ask me. Thank for any help**

Answer (score 0):

`merger.add` is an asynchronous call.

```
await merger.add(file)
```